# Search both parent and child titles and return results based on either match

Tags: php, laravel, database, eloquent

How can I make so it searches for either `projects.title` or `items.title` and still returns the result if it only matches one of them? Right now if it matches an item, it will not show up unless it matches a project title as well and the other way around. I understand why, but I probably can't eager load to do what I need right?

```php
$query = Auth::user()->projects()->where('projects.title', 'LIKE', "%$this->search%");

$query->with(['items' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('items.title', 'LIKE', "%$this->search%");
    $query->with('tags');
}]);

$query->get();
```

I guess I need something like "if it matches one or several item titles, return filtered items and the related project(s). If it matches the project title only, return the project(s) and all related items". Ideas?

Got it to work with the following (as well as a similar query on the with part):

```php
$user->projects()->with('items')->where(function($query){
  $query->where('title', 'like', '...')->orWhereHas('items', function($query){
    $query->where('title', 'like', '...');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the condition to closure:

```
$data = Auth::user()
            ->projects()
            ->with(['items' => function ($query) {
                $query
                    ->where('projects.title', 'LIKE', "%$this->search%")
                    ->orWhere('items.title', 'LIKE', "%$this->search%")
                    ->with('tags');
            }])->get();
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I tried that and it can't see projects from inside the with function. I'll try it again.